# do while Loop with & not looping properly c++

Tags: c++, do-while, binary-operators

When a value between 1 to 7 is entered the program should check the condition which is ifthe value is 1 to 7 and if the value in the entered number's array is not 0but the problem with this program is that, if the value House[0] or other array is 0 the program did not loop it keeps running

```
    do
            {
              cout << "Player 1\n";
              cout << "Please choose your location (1 to 7) => ";
              cin >> h1in ; // player 1 enters a value
              cin.clear();// used to clear the value if a str value is entered
              cin.ignore(1000,'\n');// used to clear the value if a str value is entered
              if ((h1in<1)||(h1in>7))
              {
                  cout << "You entered the wrong input \n\n";
              }
              if(house[h1in-1]==0)
              {
                  cout<<"jde";
              }

            } while((house[h1in-1]!=0)&(h1in<1)||(h1in>7));
if (h1in==1)
         {
           for(int i=1;i<7;i++){

            house[0]--;
            house[i]++;
            if(i==6){
                storehouse[0]++;
                seeds--;
                house[0]--;
            }
            printout();

           }

           }
          else if(h1in==2)
          {
             for(int i=1;i<7;i++){
               house[1]--;
               house[i+1]++;
               if(i==6){
                storehouse[0]++;
                seeds--;
                house[1]--;

               }
               printout();
             }
          }
          else if(h1in==3)
          {
              for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
              {
                  house[2]--;
                  house[i+2]++;
                  if(i==6){
                    storehouse[0]++;
                    seeds--;
                    house[2]--;
                  }
                  printout();
              }
          }
          else if(h1in==4)
          {
              for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
              {
                  house[3]--;
                  house[i+3]++;
                  if(i==6){
                    storehouse[0]++;
                    seeds--;
                    house[3]--;
                  }
                  printout();
              }
          }
           else if(h1in==5)
           {
               for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
               {
                  house[4]--;
                  house[i+4]++;
                  if(i==6){
                    storehouse[0]++;
                    seeds--;
                    house[4]--;
                  }
                  printout();
               }
           }
           else if(h1in==6)
             {
               for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
               {
                  house[5]--;
                  house[i+5]++;
                  if(i==6){
                    storehouse[0]++;
                    seeds--;
                    house[5]--;
                  }
                  printout();
               }
             }
            else if(h1in==7)
            {
                for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
                {
                  house[6]--;
                  house[i+6]++;
                  if(i==6){
                    storehouse[0]++;
                    seeds--;
                    house[6]--;
                  }
                  printout();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I now prefer to use the names `and`, `or` and `not` provided by standard C++, to make the code more clear and readable, and avoid mishaps like writing `&` instead of `&&`. With Visual C++, which is a bit challenged in this area, you can use a forced include of `<ios646.h>` to make this approach work.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is bitwise `and`. It preforms a binary `and` on each bit of the operands. You want the `&&` operator which is logical `and`.

You should also add some parenthesis to make the final line:

```
while( (house[h1in-1]!=0) && ((h1in<1)||(h1in>7)));
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: @Teeban Your question is not very clear. Also you don't show where `house[h1in-1]` is ever assigned to. Maybe you don't want `and` at all, you may be looking for `or` instead.